# Source name when writing to event viewer C#

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

How do you change the source name when writing to the event viewer in C# language?

Currently have this

> string cs = "Application";
>
> ```
>             if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
>             EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, "ReceiveDaily");
>             EventLog.WriteEntry(cs, message.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
> ```

If I change CS to anything else, I see a Security-Kerberos (0x7) popping up at my event viewer
It writes the error in the errorlog when I put "Application" though. But then the source is "Application", which isn't a very good description from where it comes ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to run your app in admin mode to create an event source.

Comment: Is it enough when you are logged in as an admin?

Comment: Not unless you disable User Account Control (UAC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil mentions, I don't think that you can dynamically create event sources unless you are running in admin mode.

However, if you know the set of sources that your application needs, then you can pre-install them using a `System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller` and `InstallUtil.exe`.  These sources will then be available to use by your application.

[This has a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of setting up the installer.

Comment: Which file do you run in admin mode then from the explorer? The coding file?

Comment: I mean, can you debug as admin? Or should I publish it first?

Comment: You compile then installer, the run installutil from an admin command prompt with the compiled all as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run your app in admin mode.

You can do this from explorer by right clicking on your app and selecting 'Run as administrator'.

Alternatively you could [add a manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227187/uac-need-for-console-application) to your app so that it automatically requests admin privileges when run.

The final (and worst from a security point of view) option is to disable UAC via the control panel.