# Event viewer create Event ID C#

Tags: c#, event-viewer

Is it possible to create an Event ID linked to an error from C# debugging system?

I'm currently writing my code -which still has a small error, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601610/source-name-when-writing-to-event-viewer-c-sharp)- for making up really detailed error logs in the event viewer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an event source you must create it if don't exist :

```
string cs = "CustomSource";
EventLog elog = new EventLog();

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, cs);

int eventID = 8;
elog.Source = cs;
elog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
elog.WriteEntry(message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error,
                    eventID);
```

Comment: But this has nothing to do with my problem?

Comment: What is your problem ? From your question i can't figure out what your problem really is .

Comment: That is the problem in my other question. If you see event viewer, you get a series of event ID's next to a certain event (warning, information, ect.). If you do a regular writing to the event viewer, it gets Event ID 0, but I want certain events to be linked at certain IDs, or to create new IDs linked to C# events